# Can a point of inflection exist at a cusp?

Tags: calculus

Can a point of inflection exist at a cusp?  I find differing opinions on this.  Lots of people say that the definition of a point of inflection is simply where the sign of the concavity changes, whether it is a smooth change or abrupt (discontinuous) change.

But some definitions require a tangent at the point of inflection:
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Point_of_inflection
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point

Which definition is correct?  Or are there multiple definitions?

Comment: The typical definition is any point *on* a curve where the sign of the curvature changes. This does mean that curvature can change at a point of discontinuity and not be an inflection point (because the change does not occur on the curve). That said, I've seen the term used in both manners. The definition only matters in as much as it deals with these pathologies appropriately in whatever context you're using them. Remember, all definitions are *correct* so long as they are used consistently within a given context.

Comment: Thanks.  It helps me to know that there's more than one interpretation.